# How do I read a sas7bdat file into C

Tags: c, sas

I’m on my journey to learn how to code C.  I’m coming from python so it is quiet a jump.

Could anyone tell me how to read a sas7bdat file into C data structs dynamically?  Meaning I don’t know how many rows or columns are in the data file itself until I get them in.

Or is this not possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the python sas7bdat library. I am not aware of an open source C variant.

Comment: Thank you. I’m trying to move from python to C. I wasn’t s it e if there is standard c syntax to read in a sas7bdat file.

Comment: SAS is written on C so you'd be reading it in its native language. Pretty cool! I am unaware of anyone who has tried to replicate this in C other than WPS. You could certainly study some of the open source packages that do read sas7bdat files and replicate the functionality.

Comment: I am not sure of the move to C. Consider going toward C# and sticking with OOP vs procedural. The sas7bdat is a complex beast. Best to stick with the library that is out there which is Python. That said, if you want to do it in C start with the sas xpt formats. C routines there will provide a sense and they are documented. The sas7bdat is not documented outside of SAS. The SAS xpt format documentation has errors in it that I found, especially the new one (v8xpt).